# How to add fireshot addons?

Tags: opera, add-on

I'm trying to install Fireshot addon in opera version 11.62. bt it is not available on opera. Actually fireshot is the extension use for taking screenshot of the current locating site so to make report on the site. so is their any option beside that or can i install Fireshot on it?

Answer (score 1):

Fireshot is a Firefox extension, I don't believe it's available as an Opera extension. You could try installing [Lightshot](https://addons.opera.com/en/addons/extensions/details/lightshot-screenshot-tool/0.1/?display=en), which sounds like it tries to do something similar (though some of the comments make it sound like it's a bit dodgy), or one of many third-party apps like [Screenshot Captor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html).

Comment: Unwanted russian addons installed with the Lightshot installer. And no online editing is working with it.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but as I said, reading through some of the comments made it sound dodgy. Sounds like it should be uninstalled (and in fact reported to Opera), so you might be better off using a third-party app (or writing your own extension) if you use this a lot, or, if you do this only infrequently, you could right-click on the page, `Open with` > `Firefox` and use Fireshot if you can't find an appropriate equivalent.

Comment: i tried Fireshot already, but i've to check the application's browser compatibility and recent i'm testing the application on opera v11.62 so i like to use some widget like that but lightshot is not so much effective as i  think.

Comment: @devilsmind: As I said, in that case your main option would be to use a third-party app. Or just live with the default screenshots (e.g. `Alt`+`PrintScreen` on Windows-based machines).

Comment: then could u list some of third party applications to support that featurs in opera...

Comment: Google is your friend. http://www.snapfiles.com/downloadfind.php?action=s&st=screenshot can get you started; it's where I got the suggestion for Screenshot Captor in my answer. I'm assuming Windows as your OS, since you haven't specified otherwise. But your question was about installing a Firefox extension in Opera, which I believe I have answered (no, you can't install it in Opera; I've named an Opera extension that sounds like it may be similar and pointed out it was dodgy; and even gave an example of a third-party app). Please don't continue to move the goalposts.

Comment: Can u say why uploading being failed while uploading images on Lightshot third-party app. or some tips for that.

Comment: No, I can't. As I said in the last comment, _Please don't continue to move the goalposts_. Your question has been answered, please ask new ones as a separate question, and please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is NOT possible for an Opera extension to do it, though we are working on exposing such functionality in the future through extensions.